# NOUN or ADVERB parts of speech

Tags: nouns, adverbs, parts-of-speech

"It was almost midnight when i reached home" .

in this sentence " home" funtion as  noun or adverb.

kindly clarify

Comment: Direct objects "should" be substantives  like nouns, not modifiers like adverbs.

Comment: 'I reached home' is the easy one. It's 'Is John home now?'

Comment: Try putting the preposition 'at'  in front of the noun.  If the meaning is unchanged then the noun is being used adverbially.

Comment: Just a note, because I have seen _reached_ being used instead of _arrived_ before: this is not standard. You _reach the station_, and you _arrive at the station_. This is not what you asked, yet it might be relevant.